# how to use SymPy or other library to have a numerical solution

Tags: sympy

I was trying to solve two equations for two unknown symbols 'Diff' and 'OHs'. the equations are shown below

```
x = (8.67839580228369e-26*Diff + 7.245e-10*OHs**3 + 
1.24402291559836e-10*OHs**2 + OHs*(-2.38073807380738e-19*Diff - 
2.8607855978291e-18) - 1.01141409254177e-29)

J= (-0.00435840284294195*Diff**0.666666666666667*(1 + 
3.64525434266056e-7/OHs) - 1)

solution = sym.nsolve ((x, J), (OHs, Diff), (0.000001, 0.000001))
print (solution)
```

is this the correct way to solve for the two unknowns?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I edited your equation per Vialfont's comments.

I would say it is a possible way but you could do better by noticing that the `J` equation can be solved easily for `OHs` and substituted into the `x` equation. This will then be much easier for `nsolve` to solve:

```
>>> osol = solve(J, OHs)[0]  # there is only one solution
>>> eq = x.subs(OHs,osol)
>>> dsol = nsolve(eq, 1e-5)
>>> eq.subs(Diff,dsol) # verify
4.20389539297445e-45
>>> osol.subs(Diff,dsol), dsol
(-2.08893263437131e-12, 4.76768525775849e-5)
```

But this is still pretty ill behaved in terms of scaling...proceed with caution. And I would suggest writing `Diff**Rational(2,3)` instead of `Diff**0.666666666666667`. Or better, then let `Diff` be `y**3` so you are working with a polynomial in `y`.

```
>>> y = var('y', postive=True)
>>> yx=x.subs(Diff,y**3)
>>> yJ=J.subs(Diff,y**3)
>>> yosol=solve(yJ,OHs)[0]
>>> yeq = yx.subs(OHs, yosol)
```

Now, the solutions of eq will be where its numerator is zero so find the real roots of that:

```
>>> ysol = real_roots(yeq.as_numer_denom()[0])
>>> len(ysol)
1
>>> ysol[0].n()
0.0362606728976173
>>> yosol.subs(y,_)
-2.08893263437131e-12
```

That is consistent with our previous solution, and this time the solutions in `ysol` were exact (given the limitations of the coefficients). So if your `OHs` solution should be positive, check your numbers and equations.

Comment: thanks Smichr! this is great help for a beginner like me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions do not meet Sympy requirements, including the exponential expressions. May be it is easier to start with a simpler system to solve with two unknowns and only a square such as:

```
from sympy.abc import a,b,x, y 
from sympy import solve,exp
eq1= a*x**2 + b*y+ exp(0)
eq2= x + y + 2
sol=solve((eq1, eq2),(x,y),dict=True)
```

`sol` includes your answers and you have access to solutions with `sol[0][x]` and `sol[0][y]`. Giving values to the parameters is done with the `.sub()` method:

```
sol[0][x].subs({a:1, b:2}) #gives -1
sol[0][y].subs({a:1, b:2}) #gives -1
```